# xerces-3.1.1 cannot create dll on MSYS?

Tags: xerces, mingw32, msys

I build xeces-3.1.1 with mingw-gcc on MSYS. I configured with `--prefix=/c/open-source/install/xerces-3.1.1 --enable-shared` but no dll is found in the installation directory. Anything wrong?

BR, Ruochen

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

```
make libxerces_c_la_LDFLAGS="-release 3.1 -no-undefined"
```

See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-c-users/201111.mbox/%3Cboris.20111103155709@codesynthesis.com%3E